# Arranging header by their code point from low to high?

Tags: codepoint

I am looking to arange my headers based on their code point from low to high.  Below is my attempt and I was wondering if someone could advise me on whether I have done this correctly.  I basically looked up the ASCII chart ([ASCII Chart](http://www.asciitable.com/))to do this manually.

```
 Action -> X-Amz-Algorithm -> X-Amz-Credential -> X-Amz-Date -> X-Amz-SignedHeaders - > X-Amz-Signature
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *sort* the headers. Depending on the programming language, this looks different, but the key word is always "sort".

Java example:

```
List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("Action", "X-Amz-Algorithm", "...");

headers.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```